# RatingBar not showing correct amount of stars

Tags: android, ratingbar

When I have numStars set to '5' I only see 4 stars and when I have it set to 6 I see 5, but then when I vote for the full 5 in app the toast says "6.0" as the rating which is not what I want. Any help would be great, I'm still new to this.

I've tried changing the java code so that it took 1 integer away from the rating, but then when I tried to give 0 stars the toast said -1. I was however getting 5 stars when I had all 5 selected with this method.

```
            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="6"
                android:isIndicator="false"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_standard"
                android:rating="3.5"
                android:stepSize="0.1"/>
```

```
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener
            (new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                            float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    String myRating = (getString(R.string.my_rating) +
                            String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating()));
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), myRating,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When I have 5 numStars I get a visual of 4 stars, but the rating is still out of 5. I want the visual to line up with what my toast displays.

Comment: - Remove padding and stepSize from xml.
-  set   android:numStars="5"

Comment: I think due to stepsize htis is happening

Answer (score 2):

In this style is the issue

You defined **style :- @android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar.Small**

In this style, size is predefined so that only you can't get 6 stars or more in properly. So it starts to adjust in 5 stars.

So you have to **change your style** or change **android:numStars="6"** to **android:numStars="5"**

Then, It will work definitely.

**Note:-** You can also use this style:- @android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar

Answer (score 0):

The `padding` in RatingBar is the culprit, set `paddingVertical` and avoid padding or `paddingHorizontal`